# Python regex matching unicode emoticons

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I am trying to build a regex to match different possible combinations of negative unicode emoticons. I am having a problem matching the types of emoticons contained in the list test_2 below. Although I believe that the non-alphanumeric symbols  that conform the emoticons are correctly placed inside the regex, neither the emoticons nor the left eye (captured group with the name eye1) are matched... How could I solve it? Thanks

```
neg_emoticon_regular = ur"""
  [\(（]?     #optional left parenthesis
  \s*         #optional space   
  [\`\#\ ́]?   #optional symbols between left parenthesis and left eye
  (?P<eye1>[\ｰ\; \́\`\・\>Tt\ー\ ̄\−\-\゚~\_\.\>\*\/]) #left eye
  \s*         #optional space                     
  [\｡\。\Δ\-\人\O\0\.\Д\д\o\−\＿\ω\ヘ\^\_]? #mouth
  \s*         #optional space  
  [(?P=eye1)\`\<\’]   #right eye, usually will match left eye                
  [\A\#\;]?   #optional symbols between right eye and right parenthesis
  \s*         #optional space
  [\)\）]?    #optional right parenthesis   
"""

neg_emoticon_re = re.compile(neg_emoticon_regular, re.VERBOSE  | re.UNICODE)
test_2 = ["(−_−＃)","(-｡-;","(-_-)"] #negative emoticons to match
for e in test_2:
    e_uc_norm = unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', e.decode("utf-8"))
    m = neg_emoticon_re.search(e_uc_norm) 
    if m: print "eye1:",m.group("eye1") #print the symbol that is supposed to be the left eye
    print len(neg_emoticon_re.findall(e_uc_norm)), e_uc_norm
```

Comment: the regex is unreadable. You could add comments, split it, use `re.escape` to avoid escaping characters by hand.

Comment: Thanks. I added some comments of the different parts.

Comment: `left eye`, `mouth` are good comments. `optional space`, `optional left parenthesis` and the like are bad. Use the same rules as for source code comments e.g., **never write**: `++i; // increment i`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a regex, `[...]` is a set of characters, so `[\(（]` will match either and open parenthesis or a space (it can be shortened to `[( ]`), and `[\s+]?` will match an optional whitespace character or a plus sign.

Comment: Thanks! I do not agree with the first part: I think that `[\(（]` will match two types of open parenthesis, either  "(" or "（" (the latter has unicode code \uff08) . about the s+, I agree, my mistake...

Comment: Ah, OK, it's just not that clear. You don't need to escape most of those characters; you certainly don't need to escape those lying outside the ASCII range.

Comment: I see... I just escaped everything just in case. This is my first try with python regex...

Comment: it might be worth mentioning explicitly that `(?P=eye1)` inside `[]` won't work.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian Thanks! How could I get the contents of the captured group and use it in the same expression?

Comment: Finally could retrieve the contents of the captured group with (?: (?P=eye1) | [\`\<\’\ ́\;] ) for the right eye (which means, either match the captured left eye OR a particular character from the group between [] )

Comment: Matthew, it looks like @DT is trying to match both normal ASCII parens and the full-width versions at U+FF08, U+FF09. There are actually five code points whose NFKC ("k/compat" composition) is the same as LEFT PARENTHESIS: run my `unichars 'NFKC =~ /^\($/'` program if you have it. Since his code is explicitly putting the string to be searched into NFKC first (just as my [unichars](http://training.perl.com/scripts/unichars) example does) in his `e_uc_norm` variable, you don’t ever need to specify the multiple forms of parens.